# ReplacementDataSet with Maven DBUnit plugin

Tags: maven, junit, dbunit

I'd like to use a ReplacementDataSet with DbUnit so that at build time I can parse my testdata.xml file and filter some data values.

E.g., it would be nice to be able to do something like this:

```
ReplacementDataSet rds = new ReplacementDataSet(ds);

rds.addReplacementObject("[NULL]", null);
rds.addReplacementObject("[NOW]", dbUnitDateFormat(DateUtils.addDays(new Date(), 0)));
```

However, the maven dbunit plug doesn't allow me to override the FlatXmlDataSetBuilder or insert any kind of replacement data set class. Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven dbunit plugin is quite basic. The dbunit ANT task allows some additional configuration behaviour but it too cannot access the full range of dbunit functionality.

Best recomemndation is to declare the use of this dataset from within your Unit tests.